# Extract regex match from a string in SystemVerilog using svlib

Tags: regex, posix, system-verilog

I am a new user of THE `svlib` package in the SystemVerilog environment. Refer to [Verilab svlib](http://www.verilab.com/resources/svlib/).  I have following sample text:

```
{'PARAMATER': 'lollg_1', 'SPEC_ID': '1G3HSB_1'}
```

and I want to use a regex to extract `1G3HSB` from this text.

I am using the following code snippet, but I am getting the whole line instead of only the extracted string.

```
wordsRe = regex_match(words[i], "\'SPEC_ID\': \'(.*?)\'");
$display("This is the output of Regex: %s", wordsRe.getStrContents())
```

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?
The output I am getting :

```
{'PARAMATER': 'lollg_1', 'SPEC_ID': '1G3HSB_1'}
```

And, I want to get:

```
1G3HSB_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to get the contents of the first capturing group with `getMatchString(1)`. Also, you need to use a greedy quantifier (lazy ones are not POSIX compliant) and a negated bracket expression - `[^']*` instead of `.*?`:

```
wordsRe = regex_match(words[i], "\'SPEC_ID\': \'([^\']*)\'");
$display("This is the output of Regex: %s", wordsRe.getMatchString(1))
```

See the User Guide details:

> `getMatchString(m)` is always exactly equivalent to calling the range method on the *Str* object containing the string that was searched:
>
> ```
> range(getMatchStart(m), getMatchLength(m))
> ```

Comment: Just did it. :D 
BTW Wiktor, could you explain why .*? would not work and [^']* would? Thanks in advance.

Comment: POSIX regex does not support lazy quantifiers. To match as few chars as possible between two chars, you need to use negated bracket expressions/character classes.